# C# UWP Open web Url with Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, url, uwp, microsoft-edge

I want open a URL using Microsoft Edge in my UWP. Searching, I found this code:

```csharp
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.ComponentModel; 

private void button_Help_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.bing.com");
}
```

But it shows the following error:

> The name Process do not exist in the current context

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, it only shows generate class options.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) is a traditional method used in .NET Framework which can't be used in UWP apps directly. To open web URI with Microsoft Edge in UWP, we can use 
[Launcher.LaunchUriAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx). For example:

```
// The URI to launch
string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.bing.com";

// Create a Uri object from a URI string 
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

// Launch the URI
async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Launch the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

   if (success)
   {
      // URI launched
   }
   else
   {
      // URI launch failed
   }
}
```

However this will open the URI with the default web browser. To always open it with Microsoft Edge, we can use [Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri, LauncherOptions) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx) with specified [LauncherOptions.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.targetapplicationpackagefamilyname.aspx). `TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName` property can specify the target package that should be used to launch a file or URI. For Microsoft Edge, its **Package Family Name** is **"Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"**. Following is an example shows how to use this.

```
// The URI to launch
string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.bing.com";
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

async void LaunchWithEdge()
{
   // Set the option to specify the target package
   var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
   options.TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName = "Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe";

   // Launch the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);

   if (success)
   {
      // URI launched
   }
   else
   {
      // URI launch failed
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, all sound logic, but I dont know why I am getting error: "The type 'IAsyncAction' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'." in Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync line.

Comment: @Julius This is a strange error. I tested the code in my side, and it works well. After a few search, I found a similar issue [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/05/20/win10-apps-in-net-common-library-issues/), please check **IAsyncAction** in this blog. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your link, in my side I found similar things, clean install.

Comment: Is there any link which captures the return result from the browser which is opened by LaunchUriAsync

Answer (score 4):

You can do it, but Microsoft Edge must be your default browser. See the code bellow

```
private async void launchURI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      
{       
     // The URI to launch
     var uriBing = new Uri(@"http://www.bing.com");

     // Launch the URI
     var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing);             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it works for me without setting Edge as default browser:

```
 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("microsoft-edge:https://www.bing.com"));
```